# UINavigationBar translucent removes the image which added on navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Earlier I want to scroll `UIView` below the `navigation bar`,
SO, I set

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

After setting the `translucent` to `NO`

The background navigationImage is missing. Its completely white in colour.

No idea what went wrong here. Please find the below image about the `navigation Bar`.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]
                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsCompact];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Your feedback is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIBarMetricsDefault` instead of `UIBarMetricsCompact`

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"] forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: I used UIBarMatricsDefault too same issue.